# Display holidays on antd's datepicker

Tags: datepicker, antd

Can someone tell me how to display holidays using antd-datepicker by getting holiday information from a server.

Before I call the dateRender callback, I want to get the startdate and the enddate of the holiday information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this picking from the [example](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-date-render):

```
<DatePicker
   dateRender={(current) => {
    const style = {};
    if (InHolidayDates(current.date())) {
      style.border = '1px solid #1890ff';
      style.borderRadius = '50%';
    }
    return (
      <div className="ant-calendar-date" style={style}>
        {current.date()}
      </div>
    );
  }}/>
```

Write a InHolidayDates(date) function which checks if the "date" is in the Holidays Date list. If it exists it returns true. Else false.

Let me know if you need help with the fetching and comparison of dates.

Comment: .Thans for your answer,

Comment: The solution I want is to get holiday information through Ajax before the date panel is displayed or switched, and then set the date style.@Shivam Gupta

Comment: Right, so the InHolidayDates() should be an ajax call which will get the info for you. 

Also, if you want you can also do the ajax call in the componentDidMount() of your component. 
This way the InHolidayDates() will just use the state (which should have the dates from the CDM() call) to check if your current date should be styled or not

Comment: But I wasn't a single request,

Comment: That's fine you can do as many request as you want in the componentDidMount()